# k package manager - discovering packages

Tags: c#, asp.net, kpm

I am playing with ASP.NET 5. As part of that effort, I'm learning about the k package manager. I have my project.json file with a number of packages and everything is working. However, now I need to figure out what other packages I can use. I'm particularly interested to find an Google Maps API (C#) package that I can use in my app.

How do you find/search/discover packages with the k package manager?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio, or are you on some other platform? What's your dev environment like?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe there's no easy way to discover packages yet. It is pre-release alpha software. You will have to manually search the [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) gallery and when you find a package you want to try out, add a reference to it in your `project.json` file.

Comment: @mason - how do you add a reference to a NuGet package in a project.json file? I was under the impression they are two different systems on two-different runtimes.

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file). You list your dependencies in your `project.json` file. The system will then pull in the packages